# Asynchronous routing and parameter passing

Tags: java, apache-camel

```
from(routeA)
.process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //Point X
        int requestId = logRequestToDatabase(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
        // need to use this requestId at point Y and Z..
    }
})
.wireTap(routeT)
.to(routeB)
.process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //Point Y
        // i need the requestId from X here to mark it to log the response to database...
    }
});
from(routeT)
.to(routeC)
.process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //Point Z
        // i need the requestId from X here to mark it to log the response to database...
    }
});
```

I need Point X to be asynchronous. I want the `requestId` as shown in Point X to be avaliable in Y and Z. This is because, logging to a database takes time and I want it to be asynchronous so that it won't affect performance.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume logRequestToDatabase is a method, and therefore you can implement the code in that method to run async, so the Camel process method can continue. If point Y and Z need access to the result of the logRequestToDatabase invocation, you can use a JDK Future for that.

Comment: Can you tel me how do i get values @X to Y n Z? I cant use global variables, as they tend to get overlapped with each request. I mean, if there is a new request before the previous reaching point Y n Z, the old value wil be overwritten.

Comment: You can store information on the Exchange properties. They are local to the Exchange and last for its lifecycle. So for example when the logRequestToDatabase is done, it can store the result as a property on the exchange. Which you can access from Y and Z. You may have to wait at Y and Z until the result is ready. And for that the JDK Future abstraction can be used. Or some other means.

Comment: Since you use wireTap a new Exchange is created. And therefore you need to store some holder object to the exchange prior, so the holder object gets copied, so you can use that to access the value at X and Y. Such a holder could be the JDK Future.

Comment: @ Claus :Thanks for your support. I really appreciate your time and efforts to help me with this.
I found a work around for this, as it not the best approach to have unnamed Processor objects defined.

Comment: `from(routeA)
   .setProperty("REQUEST", body(String.class))
   .to(routeB)
   .setProperty("B_RESPONSE", body(String.class))
   .wireTap(routeT);
   
  from(routeT)
   .setBody(property("REQUEST"))
   .to(routeC)
   .setProperty("C_RESPONSE", body(String.class))
   .process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
     int requestId = logRequestToDatabase((String) exchange.getProperty("REQUEST"));
     //log B and C response using this requestId
    }
   });`